# NFS mount from Synology NAS, gives permission denied

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, synology

I am currently trying to use a Synology NAS to handle storage through NFS for some other computers. My current problem is that I get permissions denied, whenever I try to read or write to the NFS mount.

I have some screenshots showing my setup on the Synology NAS:
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the setup and I am using NFS 4.1.

Furthermore I have given all folders 777 permissions, so nothing (for what I know) should limit me there.

[image]

But still it gives me **permissions denied**. The mount command right now is as follows:

```bash
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.90:/volume1/nfs /nfs
```

All tutorials I have tried says this is the right configuration, but I must do something wrong, so I hope someone can help me in the right direction.

**Client machine**

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Comment: The server will look up the client ip address by dns to find the domain it is in. It must be the same as the server's.

Comment: @meuh, I can easily mount it, it is my read/write permissions that gives issues. Even though I have set the permission set to 777. Which is very insecure, but not even working.